# How to display with align?

Tags: java, printing, alignment, output, println

```
for (int j = 0; j < numStu; j++) {  
    System.out.println((j + 1) + "\t" + StudentName[j] + "\t\t\t" + (Marks[j]) + "\t" + Grade[j]);  
}
```

This is the output display for above command.

```
No. Name            Marks   Grade
1   ADRIAN TAN          46.00   C-
2   KIM CHEE LIONG HAN          76.00   A-
3   PETER LIM AH MENG           64.00   B-
4   WAYNE WALKER            23.00   F
```

The desired output is:

```
No. Name                Marks   Grade
1   ADRIAN TAN          46.00   C-
2   KIM CHEE LIONG HAN  76.00   A-
3   PETER LIM AH MENG   64.00   B-
4   WAYNE WALKER        23.00   F
```

thanks for helping.^^

Comment: Why you are asking [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23757856/1686291) again !!!!

Comment: you can use formatted print - `printf`

Answer (score 0):

You can print formatted by using `System.out.printf()` method.